# how to use magento defined blocks in our defined new block as inner block

Tags: blocks, layout

i have tried to use block as inner block which is defined in the same layout xml file using "as" in block tag and getchildhtml("as name") in phtml.
test.php(layout file)

```
<block name="name1" type="modulename/blockfilename" template="file1.phtml">
  <block name="name2" type=modulename1/blockfilename1" template="file2.phtml" as="display"></block>
</block>
```

file1.phtml

```
<?php $this->getChildhtml("display") ?>
```

similarly how can we use the magento defined blocks as inner blocks in our blocks
for example magento defined 
Now i want to use as="left" in my block as inner block

If possible can you please let me know with example for better understanding.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You use;

```
<?php $this->getChildhtml("display") ?>
```

when you should use:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildhtml("display") ?>
```

To clarify, `getChildHtml()` only returns a string and you must do something with it like, in this case, echo it.